# Почему темный фон при вызове гамбургер-меню появляется резко?

Tags: html, css

При вызове гамбургер-меню слишком резко появляется темный фон .bg, хотя для него задан transition: 0.3s. Изначально у .bg стоит display: none, но при нажатии на бургер к .bg добавляется класс .bg_show, который имеет свойство display: block, но transition так и не работает. Почему?

Сайт http://ilyin1ib.beget.tech/

Весь код jsfiddle.net/mp1ykq0e/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]